# Bypass Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication

I have an ASP.NET intranet application that is configured to run in Integrated Windows authentication mode. It has been working fine until a need came up recently.

What the need is that the Intranet needs to be checked for availability by an availability checker which is a Windows service. What the checker does is hit an ASP.NET page and examine the response object. Since the windows service is not running with a domain user account, it gets

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I am thinking of adding a new asp.net page for the checker to use and I want to tell the system not to authenticate it. But I believe the authentication happens before the application even gets a chance to review the page, that the 401 error is returned before the application code "sees" the page.

What are my options to get by this?

Thanks!

John

Comment: Did anything work with you? I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Besides adding a new folder, as @GordonBell commented, you can use the `location` element in your root web.config file.

Example:

```
  <location path="YourFile.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Yes, good point.  Although that should be allow users="?" for anonymous.

Comment: @GordonBell Your comment is not accurate. `*` means _all users_. `?` means anonymous users. Therefore `<allow users="*"` means **allow all users**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add a new folder to your website (for example: /Check)

In /Check, create new web.config containing:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then anything you access in /Check shouldn't be authenticated.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know i only had 5 minutes to edit my comments. I tried the "Check" folder approach but got this error: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (E:\Root\Intranet\check\web.config line 3). 
Also I'd like to add that this application is running in IIS 7 classic mode.